# Проверка цепи сертификатов X509 на то, что они были удостоверены

Tags: java, криптография, валидация, сертификат, x509certificate

Первоначально была назначена только проверка подписи, а теперь еще необходимо проверять то, что сертификаты нормальные. Моя "нормальность" заключалась в том, что я тупо смотрел дату действия конечного сертификата(ключа подписи), а также брал оттуда CRL и смотрел, что документ был подписан до даты отзыва и даты окончания действия сертификата. А теперь я открыл методичку и О УЖАС - узнал оттуда, что также нужно проверять не только конечный сертификат, а также всю цепь сертификатов, которая должна выглядеть в России так:

```
- Доверенный корневой самоподписанный сертификат – сертификат Головного удостоверяющего центра (ГУЦ) Минкомсвязи России (ПАК "Головной удостоверяющий центр") 

-- Промежуточные доверенные сертификаты ПАК "УЦ 1 ИС ГУЦ" и ПАК "УЦ 2 ИС ГУЦ" 

--- Сертификаты аккредитованных УЦ 

---- Сертификаты ключа подписи
```

Ну <strike>скомуниздил</strike> написал я код который, значит, рекурсивно пробегается по цепи сертификатов, имея входными данными конечный сертификат, пока не дойдет до самоподписанного. (Имеем статический List, до входа в метод добавляется конечный сертификат)

```
private static void getRootCertificate(X509Certificate endEntityCert)
   {
       try
       {
           X509Certificate rootCertificate = null;
           CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
           byte[] extVal = endEntityCert.getExtensionValue(Extension.authorityInfoAccess.getId());

           if(extVal != null)
           {
               AuthorityInformationAccess aia = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(extVal));

               AccessDescription[] descriptions = aia.getAccessDescriptions();
               for (AccessDescription ad : descriptions)
               {
                   // check if it's a URL to issuer's certificate
                   if (ad.getAccessMethod().equals(X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_ad_caIssuers))
                   {
                       GeneralName location = ad.getAccessLocation();
                       if (location.getTagNo() == GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier)
                       {
                           String issuerUrl = location.getName().toString();
                           // http URL to issuer (test in your browser to see if it's a valid certificate)
                           // you can use java.net.URL.openStream() to create a InputStream and create
                           // the certificate with your CertificateFactory
                           URL url = new URL(issuerUrl);
                           rootCertificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(url.openStream());
                       }
                   }
               }

               if (rootCertificate != null)
               {
                   certificatesChain.add(rootCertificate); // <-Добавляем в стат лист
                   getRootCertificate(rootCertificate);
               }
           }

       } catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    } // Госпаде, на стаке вообще когда-нибудь код нормально помещается? Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, я застрелюсь
```

И он, вроде, отрабатывает. Проблема в том, что нам необходимо удостовериться, что 1-ый(не конечный, который 0) является не простым парнем, а аккредитованным УЦ. В методичке я нашел способ это проверить. Перейти по адресу https://e-trust.gosuslugi.ru/CA/DownloadTSL?schemaVersion=0 (осторожно, прямая ссыль на скачку). И там уже найти название этого сертификата. Собственно, вопрос. По какому конкретному критерию мы сравниваем то, что там именно этот сертификат? По серийному номеру? Выглядит это так:

```
  <ПрограммноАппаратныеКомплексы>
      <ПрограммноАппаратныйКомплекс>
        <Псевдоним>УЦ ООО НПО КРИСТА</Псевдоним>
        <КлассСредствЭП>КС3</КлассСредствЭП>
        <Адрес>
          <Страна>RU</Страна>
          <Регион>
            <Код>76</Код>
            <Название>Ярославская область</Название>
          </Регион>
          <Индекс>152915</Индекс>
          <УлицаДом>1-я Выборгская 50</УлицаДом>
          <Город>Рыбинск</Город>
        </Адрес>
        <СредстваУЦ>КриптоПро УЦ 1.5</СредстваУЦ>
        <КлючиУполномоченныхЛиц>
          <Ключ>
            <ИдентификаторКлюча>852C50C1B9C7356E7C1D39216FF5EE92F7E8130D</ИдентификаторКлюча>
            <АдресаСписковОтзыва>
              <Адрес>http://ca.krista.ru/crl/CAKristaNPO.crl</Адрес>
            </АдресаСписковОтзыва>
            <Сертификаты>
              <ДанныеСертификата>
                <Отпечаток>0A402EC78C4B1ECCB5C390AB678E11947A8D7F4F</Отпечаток>
                <КемВыдан>CN=УЦ 1 ИС ГУЦ, C=RU, S=77 г. Москва, L=Москва, O=Минкомсвязь России, STREET=125375 г. Москва ул. Тверская д.7, E=dit@minsvyaz.ru, ОГРН=1047702026701, ИНН=007710474375</КемВыдан>
                <КомуВыдан>CN=УЦ ООО НПО КРИСТА, OU=Удостоверяющий центр, O=ООО НПО Криста, L=Рыбинск, S=Ярославская, C=RU, E=ca@krista.ru, STREET=1-я Выборгская 50, ИНН=007707758779, ОГРН=1117746753871</КомуВыдан>
                <СерийныйНомер>2CB3631E00000000023B</СерийныйНомер>
                <ПериодДействияС>2013-12-04T10:38:00Z</ПериодДействияС>
                <ПериодДействияДо>2017-12-04T11:47:00Z</ПериодДействияДо>
                <Данные>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</Данные>
              </ДанныеСертификата>
              <ДанныеСертификата>
                <Отпечаток>05F71E1B6FFAB6B3D5B3DB70CA272914D3E6A32D</Отпечаток>
                <КемВыдан>CN=УЦ 2 ИС ГУЦ, C=RU, S=77 г.Москва, L=Москва, O=Минкомсвязь России, STREET=125375 г. Москва ул. Тверская д.7, E=dit@minsvyaz.ru, ОГРН=1047702026701, ИНН=007710474375</КемВыдан>
                <КомуВыдан>CN=УЦ ООО НПО КРИСТА, OU=Удостоверяющий центр, O=ООО НПО Криста, L=Рыбинск, S=Ярославская, C=RU, E=ca@krista.ru, STREET=1-я Выборгская 50, ИНН=007707758779, ОГРН=1117746753871</КомуВыдан>
                <СерийныйНомер>330EA0F800000000017C</СерийныйНомер>
                <ПериодДействияС>2013-12-04T10:50:00Z</ПериодДействияС>
                <ПериодДействияДо>2017-07-22T07:54:00Z</ПериодДействияДо>
                <Данные>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</Данные>
              </ДанныеСертификата>
            </Сертификаты>
          </Ключ>
        </КлючиУполномоченныхЛиц>
      </ПрограммноАппаратныйКомплекс>
    </ПрограммноАппаратныеКомплексы>
```

И еще: ну проверили мы этот сертификат, оказался он там, а дальше что? Иногда в файле просто нет промежуточного и самоподписанного сертификатов и вместо 4-ых сертификатов мы получаем только 2, а иногда даже один - конечный. Допустим, проверили конечный, УЦ его не отозвал, смотрим, что УЦ аккредитован и успех? В таком случае можно же не проверять эти ПАК и Самоподписанный минкомсвязи? Парсинг 80к строчек XML мне не очень нравится.

Answer (score 1):

> Как найти родительский сертификат?

Действительно, в сертификате пользователя не обязательно содержатся все родительские сертификаты. Поэтому у тебя должно быть хранилище сертификатов УЦ. В данном случае это твой файл. Искать родительский сертификат можно по `DN` (`IssuerDN` в сертификате пользователя) или идентификатору ключу УЦ (параметр с `OID 2.5.29.35`, необязательный, в самом сертификате УЦ он скрывается под `OID 2.5.29.14`). В каждом из указанных случае может вернуться массив. Далее проверяешь, что хотя бы один сертификат из массива подписал пользовательский сертификат (см. метод [verify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify(java.security.PublicKey))). Найденный сертификат и есть родительский.

> Придётся парсить весь файл?

От этого никуда не спрятаться. Советую тебе создать таблицу в БД, куда кешировать результаты парсинга. А сам парсинг проводить примерно раз в день.

> Как проверить, что это именно тот сертификат?

Сравнить при помощи метода `equals` два объекта типа [X509Certificate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html)

> Как проверить, что УЦ аккредитован?

У тебя должна иметься некая точка доверия. Т.е. некий список сертификатов, которым ты `доверяешь безоговорочно`. В твоём случае это опять же файл. Соответственно  сертификат считается доверенным, если он состоит в указанном списке, либо можно можно добраться по цепочке сертификатов к какому-либо из списка доверенных. Соответственно `УЦ аккредитован` = `доверяешь безоговорочно` сертификату УЦ. Как ты понял, сертификат УЦ не обязательно является самоподписанным, т.к. его может подписать другой УЦ (более старший по рангу, при наличии соответствующих полномочий). Самоподписанные сертификаты УЦ называются корневыми. Их во всём совсем немного.

P.S. Список доверенных сертификатов для `java` обычно лежит в файле `jre/lib/security/cacerts`. Также учти, что java из коробки не поддерживает алгоритмы ГОСТ, поэтому тебе потребуется накатить `КриптоПро JCP` или что-то подобное на `jre`.